# Export a table that content results value

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geojson

I import a table that have a collection of points defined by (pts), but when I call (pts) by `ee.Feature (pts)` I can not export the table.

```
var feat = ee.Feature(pts, {date: ee.Date(date), rain: rainAtDate})
```

Can I export the table that content (value result (correctFeats) ) 
for each geometry into the table?

```
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/mustafalhealy/Z_HdrologyStation')

    // Start and End Dates
    var inidate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,01,24)
    var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020,01,25)

    // Difference between start and end in days 
    var difdate = enddate.difference(inidate, 'day')

    // Import GSMaP data
    var gsmap = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational')
    .filterDate(inidate, enddate)
    .select('hourlyPrecipRate');

    // Time lapse
    var lapse = ee.List.sequence(0, difdate.subtract(1))
    var inidate = ee.Date('2020-01-24')
    var listdates = lapse.map(function(day){
      return inidate.advance(day, 'day')
    })

    // Iterate over the list of dates
    var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(listdates.iterate(function(day, ft) {
      // Cast
      ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ft)
      day = ee.Date(day)

      // Filter the collection in one day (24 images)
      var day_collection = gsmap.filterDate(day, day.advance(1, 'day'))

      // Get the sum of all 24 images into one Image
      var sum = ee.Image(day_collection.sum())

      // map over the ft to set a property over each feature
      var temp_ft = ft.map(function(feat){
        var geom = feat.geometry()
        var value = sum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 1000).get('hourlyPrecipRate')
        return feat.set(day.format('YYYY-MM-dd'), value)
      })

      // Return the FeatureCollection with the new properties set
      return temp_ft
    }, pts))

    // get the dates and the rain intensity per day
    var dates = newft.first().toDictionary().keys();
    var rain = newft.first().toDictionary().values();

    // build a feature collection with property rain and date
    var correctFeats = ee.FeatureCollection(dates.map(function(date){
      var ind = dates.indexOf(date);
      var rainAtDate = rain.get(ind);
      var feat = ee.Feature(pts, {date: ee.Date(date), rain: rainAtDate})
      return feat;
    }));
    print(correctFeats);

    //Making a chart
    //var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(correctFeats, 'date', 'rain')
    //print(chart);

    // Export the FeatureCollection.
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: correctFeats,
      description: 'Rain',
      fileFormat: 'CSV'
    });
```

[Link to demo on Google Earth Engine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a534d35234e3e726aecfb7903d6b1a8)

Comment: can i use this function to insert the value for each geometry ?pts.select([]).evaluate(function (featureCollection) 
{
  featureCollection.features.forEach(function (feature) 
  {
    
    
    
  });
});

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a question, please share all used assets. It makes it easier and faster to help you out.

When you iterate over your `pts` you return another `ee.FeatureCollection`. That's not allowed. When you map or iterate over an `ee.FeatureCollection` or `ee.ImageCollection`, you must return an `ee.Image` or an `ee.Feature`.

You could do something like this instead:

```
function calculate_rain(ft) {
  var geom = ft.geometry()
  var dayRain = listdates.map(function (day) {
    // Cast
    day = ee.Date(day)

    // Filter the collection in one day (24 images)
    var day_collection = gsmap.filterDate(day, day.advance(1, 'day'))

    // Get the sum of all 24 images into one Image
    var sum = ee.Image(day_collection.sum())
    var rain = sum
      .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 1000)
      .get('hourlyPrecipRate')
    return {day: day.format('YYYY-MM-dd'), rain: rain}
  })
  var rainDict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    dayRain.map(function (dayRain) { return ee.Dictionary(dayRain).get('day') }),
    dayRain.map(function (dayRain) { return ee.Dictionary(dayRain).get('rain') })
  )
  return ee.Feature(geom, rainDict)
}

var correctFeats = pts.map(calculate_rain)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee075278627ef26b2c819a9337a6ef66

Comment: it's still not working the table  , no valu for each point in to the table , sorry for that

Comment: It's hard to tell without having your points. The script exported values.

Comment: you can cheek the Link https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a534d35234e3e726aecfb7903d6b1a8

Comment: can you cheek the Link ,  table that does not content results value for each point , pls heelp me to edit the code https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a534d35234e3e726aecfb7903d6b1a8